# Wi-fi randomly disconnects and then "Device not found"

Tags: linux-mint, wifi

I have a Dell Inspiron 15 7559 dual-boot running Windows 10 and Linux Mint 18. Mint has been running smoothly for a few months now, but recently it started randomly kicking me off the wi-fi and then what I can only assume is disabling/disconnecting wireless completely. When this happens, I don't have the option to turn wireless back on using the graphical menu, and even `iwconfig` shows my wireless isn't functioning.

`ifconfig` when wireless is functioning:

```
enp4s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr f4:8e:38:e8:72:8d  
      UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
      inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
      RX packets:301 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:301 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
      RX bytes:42394 (42.3 KB)  TX bytes:42394 (42.3 KB)

wlp5s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr ac:2b:6e:a2:71:be  
      inet addr:172.27.223.183  Bcast:172.27.223.255  Mask:255.255.254.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::ffc9:10ba:954b:335b/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:6057 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:4330 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:5329884 (5.3 MB)  TX bytes:897294 (897.2 KB)
```

The `wlp5s0` is the wireless device. When Mint kicks me off wi-fi, this is the response to `ifconfig wlp5s0`:
`error fetching interface information: Device not found`

What is the issue? Is Mint disabling my wireless card?

How can I stop this from happening?

Note: a restart of my computer usually fixes the problem until I turn it off again. Then, next time I turn it on, I have the problem all over again. A restart will fix it again. However, I can't just keep having to restart my computer.
I've also tried disabling power management, but that hasn't helped at all.

Answer (score 0):

I would try testing the wifi hardware with Ubuntu DVD and the Windows 10 already installed.  If failure is observed on Ubuntu and Windows, then it indicates a hardware problem. If the wifi works on both Windows and Ubuntu then it is in all likeliness a Mint problem.  Alternatively, a $10 Edimax USB Wifi could be used.